# Do Protestants believe in paranormal activity in modern times?

Tags: protestantism, demons, spirit, supernatural, spiritual-warfare

I've already asked my fair share of questions on the paranormal, but so far I have mainly received answers from the Catholic viewpoint. Therefore, this time I want to limit the scope of this question to the **Protestant perspective**.

**According to Protestants, are there genuine cases of paranormal activity in modern times?** If so, is there agreement among Protestants as to the causes? Are genuine cases of paranormal activity caused by God, angels, demons, the disembodied spirits of the dead, people endowed with psychic abilities or something else?

---

Related questions:

- [How common have reports of paranormal activity and ghost or spirit apparitions been among Christians throughout history?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/89056/50422)
- [Which denominations believe that demons can cause physical harm to Christians?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/87240/50422)
- [Are there any documented cases of paranormal activity preceding or during an exorcism?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/80515/50422)
- [How often do missionaries report encounters with demonic activity while deployed to countries belonging to the 10/40 Window?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/82874/50422)
- [Do Christians believe in witchcraft and the occult?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/84082/50422)
- [Is there any biblical basis to support demonic paranormal activity?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/80419/50422)
- [According to Evangelical Presbyterians, do ghosts exist?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/44557/50422)
- [What is the Full Preterist perspective on ghosts and paranormal activity?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/53105/50422)

Comment: This is one criticism I tend to bring up to my protestant friends. Did demons just stop possessing people after the apostles?

Comment: I do.  I have experienced my fair share of paranormal activity both before and after my salvation.  The difficulty, and the point of theological divergence for Protestants, is in the biblical explanation of what the heck happened.

Answer (score 1):

### Yes. Satan is a paranormal force for death in the modern world.

The answer is a fairly confident, yes. I cannot recount the number of times I have heard pastors note that "The greatest trick the Devil ever pulled was convincing the world he didn’t exist." It is hard exactly to pin down the [origins](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2018/03/20/devil/) of this quote, but it's prominent use by Protestant Pastors is representative of the dual facts that (1) Protestants believe Satan and demons are hard at work today, and (2) many in the West suspect part of their work has been to disguise their presence. As such, it is not uncommon for Protestants to connect (not conflate) certain physical and mental disorders with the work of Satan. I know pastors overseas who claim to have performed exorcisms on those that were in their opinions, clearly possessed. Meanwhile, professing protestants and long-standing medical professionals in the West have pointed to the possibility of schizophrenia's origins in demonic influence. For example, Dr. Matthew Sleeth writes in his 2021 book, *Hope Always*:

> The woman, Araceli, lived in a mud and thatch hut. Although in her early twenties, she weighed about sixty pounds. She lay in a contracted fetal position. She was nonverbal. Her only activity was to bang her head against the wall...Her distressed parents...had lost two other children around the same age from the same mysterious malady..."If ever there was a woman possessed by seven demons, I was looking at her," John [a volunteer Doctor] said. Perhaps this was schizophrenia. The diagnosis, much less treatment with the drug, was uncertain. However, she was going to die within days if left untreated, and Providence had seen to it that the team had antipsychotic medicines with them. The medicines were started, and they worked. Araceli began to eat...I have before and after pictures of Araceli. Even though I know it is the same person, I wonder when I look at the change. I have a picture taken several years later, which shows a quite woman standing beside one of the Sunday school children she now teaches. She is a modern-day Mary Magdalene: a woman possessed of a demon that surely would have killed her had not the Lord intervened. (93-94)

This is but a clearly documented case of a protestant Christian in the West attributing at least partial responsibility for life-destroying mental illnesses to the direct influence of demons. Dr. Sleeth's book is on the topic of suicide, which, despite the increasing success and application of suicide prevention measures, is almost inexplicably on the rise in the West and around the world.

Comment: I would further argue that [Philosophical Naturalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naturalism_(philosophy)) is Satan's most effective lie in most of the current Western world; convinging people not only that he (Satan) doesn't exist, but that *God* doesn't exist. That lie (and the religion of Naturalism) would obviously be undermined by the demonstrated existence of supernatural influences. I've heard (very anecdotally, and could not cite a source) that countries that have not bought into that lie to the same extent experience much more overtly demonic activity. Food for thought.

Comment: `This is but a clearly documented case of a protestant Christian in the West attributing at least partial responsibility for life-destroying mental illnesses to the direct influence of demons` - I don't understand how this case shows that demons were involved. Wasn't she healed with antipsychotic medicines?

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator I'm not saying this is an indisputable case, nor even is Dr. Sleeth, I'm merely citing an example of a Western medical professional (and his fellow Doctor friend) who saw something like schizophrenia as the work of demons. In the book he details how the medicines were almost not brought but providentially were, suggesting divine intervention. He also may be suggesting that Satan and demons are not more powerful than the proper use of the material world. ie he may be able to break chains but may not be able to break diamonds and so medicine can fight demonic effects.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple I think I too heard it through CS Lewis, but as the source I cited notes, it dates from well before him.

Comment: @ninthamigo You're right.  I should have read it first :-).

Comment: "Satan and demons are not more powerful than the proper use of the material world"... or perhaps they want you to *think* that, because they find that illusion more useful to their cause. OTOH, there is also reason to believe the spiritual world's ability to interact with the physical world is indeed moderated by physical means when we're talking about *human souls*; if that's true, it would stand to reason that demons are subject to similar limitations.

Comment: @Matthew It's valid for you or I to hypothesize as such, but Dr. Sleeth's book seems to rest on the assumption that the suicide pandemic is in part caused by Demonic activity, but he also in later chapter's suggests the prevalent role alcohol and drugs play. I think certain 'material' behaviors can make our minds more susceptible to demonic activity, and that conversely, certainly healthy life habits can help strengthen your mind against these attacks. It is then not a difficult step to assume medicine may have effects that weaken demonic attacks/oppression.

Comment: @ninthamigo - good point regarding the interaction between chemicals and the demonic. There are many testimonies about people getting in touch with the spiritual realm through the consumption of psychedelic drugs such as mushrooms, DMT, ayahuasca, etc. [Shamanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamanism) is all about that.